# WQL with string finding in where clause

Tags: c#, wmi, wql

I'm looking a way to search for USB devices where the DeviceID contains the string literal `VID_217C`. Is it possible?

In other words, I'm looking for the following query

```
select * from Win32_USBHub where DeviceID contains "VID_217C"
```

to return only those `Win32_USBHub`s for which `VID_217C` is a substring in `DeviceID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [like operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392263%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
select * from Win32_USBHub where DeviceID LIKE "%VID_217C%"
```